# Inputing values into a database with Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can't for the life of me find info on how to do this despite my gut telling me its a basic fundamental.

I have a simple boolean that redirects users based on a table value reference_id. I want it to redirect the user after inputting a value in a column in that user's row.

Here is the code: (you can ignore the code I commeneted out. That's for a different implementation)

https://gyazo.com/9f2774cd9069b4678d67b80391f9f276

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $id = Auth::id();
    $rfid = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->value('reference_id');
    //$userid = User::find($id);
    if ($rfid == ''){
        //$clientRole = DB::table('roles')->where('id', '2')->value('slug');
        //$userid->attachRole($clientRole); // sets role based on redirect
        input 'client' to database 'users' column 'temproles' //dummy code for what I want to do

        view('/clientdirect');
    }
    else {
        //$employeeRole = DB::table('roles')->where('id', '3')->value('slug');
        //$userid->attachRole($employeeRole); // sets role based on redirect
        input 'employee' to database 'users' column 'temproles'
        view('/empdirect');
    }

}
```

Again my apologies if this is common knowledge, I couldn't find a reference source anywhere. Either a link to where I can read about this or directions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to input 'client' on a table called 'users' in a column 'temproles' you should be able to accomplish that by this:

```
DB::table('users')->insert(
    ['temprole' => 'client']
);
```

If you have models created you could do the following:

```
$user = new User
$user->temproles = 'client';
$user->save();
```

Comment: I'm not having a problem with the redirect. I want to edit my database. The redirect is fine